# MonetDB replication

Tags: ubuntu, database-replication, master-slave, monetdb

Does anyone create replication with MonetDB?
I've tried many times but still cannot run MonetDB in master-slave mode(replication).

I have such errors when start slave server:

- !mvc_init: unable to create system tables
- !SQLException:SQLinit:Catalogue initialization failed

I've done all that written in https://www.monetdb.org/Documentation/Cookbooks/SQLrecipes/TransactionReplication but in does no works.

Does anyone can help me?

Comment: The transaction replication feature is marked as experimental. Some assembly required.

Comment: I've also tried to do replication from sources but also couldn't run it.Can you help me with it?